# How to use ViewFlipper to dynamically add images in AppWidget like ad rotation

Tags: android, android-appwidget, viewflipper, remoteview

I'm trying to make `AppWidget` shows rotation images which can automatically change every 5 seconds,and I think `ViewFlipper` might be able to reach this goal.

But I get images from server and can't just put them as `ImageView` in `.xml` file under nested `ViewFlipper` like this:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewflipper" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_content"
 android:autostart="true" 
 android:flipinterval="5000"  > 

  <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/drawable1"/>

  <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/drawable2"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

I need to add images dynamically, and shows one picture at one time. If there's more than one image, they need to be shown on `AppWidget` by turns.

Hope somebody could help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "dynamically" you mean there could be an arbitrary number of items. What you probably want is [`AdapterViewFlipper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper.html). You can follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections) for building an AppWidget whose content is backed by an adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is what I need!